# How to access & Print Json data from Bottom to Top

Tags: php, json

I have a json data like

```
{"Nepal":"1","India":"3","Pakistan":"2","America":"25","Bangaladesh":"23"}
```

Now what I want is to print and access data from last to top
to print like this using PHP

```
Bangaladesh 23
America 25
Pakistan 2
India 3
Nepal 1
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: are you using javascript or any other language?

Comment: On Stack Overflow you thank people by upvoting helpful answers and accepting the answer which you think answers your question the best. Comments are for clarifications and/or discussions about the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do reverse loop like this using `list.length`. Code depends upon the language you are using.

```
for(var i=list.length-1;i>=0;i--){
 //your printing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Ruchan mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422826/how-to-access-print-json-data-from-bottom-to-top#answer-31423097), iterating over your JSON Array object in reverse is a solution. Here is a snippet for PHP

```
//Decode the JSON
$array = json_decode('[{"Nepal":"1","India":"3","Pakistan":"2","America":"25","Bangaladesh":"23"}]',false); //Note: Second parameter is a boolean indicating if the resulting array should be associative or not

//Get the length of the Array
$length = count($array);

//Iterate over the array from the last index to the first (ie, length-1 to 0)
while($length) {
    echo sprintf("<p>%s</p>", $array[--$length]);
}
```